# Entity Framework creates a table I don't want

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework Code First approach to have Data Access in my application. I have a table `Web_Documents` and a table `Web_Profils` and a relation table `Web_Profil_joint_Documents`, all of which I have made POCOs for. My problem is when I added a migration, Entity Framework created an extra relation's table.Now in my context I make a binding between both as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Web_Profils>()
    .HasMany<Web_Documents>(p => p.Documents)
    .WithMany(d => d.Profils)
    .Map(Web_Profil_joint_Documents =>
    {
        Web_Profil_joint_Documents.MapLeftKey("IDProfil");
        Web_Profil_joint_Documents.MapRightKey("IDDocument");
        Web_Profil_joint_Documents.ToTable("Web_Profil_joint_Documents");
    });
```

But I think this adds a new table, and since I already have `Web_Profil_joint_Documents` it creates `Web_Profil_joint_Documents1` and adding data to the first, actually fills the second. I have tried reverse engineer the tables to my model but that just created a whole mess. I've also tried deleting the tables in SQL Server Management and then manually modifying migrations to have `Web_Profil_joint_Documents` only but had error everytime.

Does this code create a new table? I thought it would add a many to many relationship between both tables and add it to the already existing relations table.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Logically, you cannot have an "instance" of `Web_Profil_joint_Documents` so it shouldn't exist in your code-first entity model. Let Entity Framework handle the many to many relation table.

Comment: @AmitJoshi Well that's just depressing :(

Comment: @ChrisPickford So no `DbSet<Web_Profil_joint_Documents>` in my context either? Would make sense to do what you say I will try. Only thing is how to test the relation? Say I want to find Row 1 of the relation table, or row where ID = 1 etc . ?

Comment: @LéonardLaiter Why you wanted to find individual ids? Everything can be achieved through related entity instances.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Hmm just to test my DB and see that everything works fine, but also that I'm quite inexperienced with no one to help me at work so sometimes I do some weird / illogical stuff ...

Comment: that's not quite true. you can pretty much control any aspect of EF (at least in the schema management). And yeah, you pretty much never need direct access to the the join table except for semi join scenarios, but you can still do that through the navigation properties. If you want to control the join table, configure two one-to-many relationships, as the .Map function expects a mapping and therefore will define a join table with a unique name, as the join object is already part of the context graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not define related entity POCO class for many to many relationship. Entity framework does generates it automatically for us. From the comment I come to know that why you had define the relationship entity.

Related entity will contain two columns.

1. Primary key of `Web_Profils`
2. Primary key of `Web_Documents`.

So far everything is simple. Now you wanted to access the data in relationship table (which is very very very rare) then you can do something like this.

suppose you have instance of web_profile and you wanted to get its record in relationship then first column is id (primary key) of instance and second you can get it by selecting id of its related collection of `Web_Profil_joint_Documents`.

```
Web_Profils.Web_Profil_joint_Documents.Select(d => d.Id)
```

so in that way you also achieve second column of relationship table.